# Move focus to combobox field instead of chip in VuetifyJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, combobox, vuetify.js, tabindex

If you go use the keyboards tab-key [in this VuetifyJS/VueJS example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Mqrvrv) the chip gets focused first and only after the second tab the **combobox textfield**. 
 How to focus the **combobox textfield** first instead of the chip?

```
<v-flex xs12 sm6 md3>
      <v-text-field label="Regular" autofocus></v-text-field>
    </v-flex>

    <v-flex xs12>
      <v-combobox v-model="select" :items="items" chips label="I use a scoped slot">
        <template slot="selection" slot-scope="data">
          <v-chip
            :selected="data.selected"
            :disabled="data.disabled"
            :key="JSON.stringify(data.item)"
            class="v-chip--select-multi "
            @input="data.parent.selectItem(data.item)"
          >
            <v-avatar class="accent white--text">
              {{ data.item.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() }}
            </v-avatar>
            {{ data.item }}
          </v-chip>
        </template>
      </v-combobox>
    </v-flex>
```

Comment: Is there any reason to have chips focusable? You can put `tabindex="-1"` on chips to make them not focusable at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) property to specify the tab order of the elements.
Following will make input focus-able before chip.

```
<v-combobox tabindex="1">
<v-chip tabindex="2">
```

To prevent element to get focus you can set `tabindex` to `-1`.
Note that default value is `0`.